# Programm tries to append list with a string although it's not allowed

Tags: list, loops, while-loop, append, max

Hello i am pretty new to python and i am currently writing this program, where i try to find the min and max in a list that is created through inputing numbers sequentialy. When i give the programm the input: 5, a, 1 it gives me the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juli/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    mx = max(list,key=float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

Code:

```
def check_for_float(p_input):
    try:
        ipt = float(p_input)
        return ipt
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("Error, not a numeric input")
        return False

list = []

while True:
    ipt = input("Please enter a numeric value: ")

    if ipt == "done":
        break

    check_for_float(ipt)

    if ipt == type(float) or type(int):
        list.append(ipt)
    elif ipt == type(str):
        continue

if list == []:
    quit()

mx = max(list,key=float)
mn = min(list,key=float)

print(f"Maximum = {mx}; Minimum = {mn}")
```

I don't know why he has trouble converting the str into a float, because normally there shouldn't even be a str in the max() function. My goal is, that the programm leaves str out that's why i put the continue function there. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this part of your code

```
if ipt == type(float) or type(int):
        list.append(ipt)
    elif ipt == type(str):
        continue
```

and add this code instead

```
check = check_for_float(ipt)
    if check:
        list.append(ipt)
    else:
        continue
```

This code will now filter out any character input and only append the valid numeric values into the list.
The complete code should look like this

```
def check_for_float(p_input):
    try:
        ipt = float(p_input)
        return ipt
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("Error, not a numeric input")
        return False

list = []

while True:
    ipt = input("Please enter a numeric value: ")

    if ipt == "done":
        break

    check = check_for_float(ipt)
    if check:
        list.append(ipt)
    else:
        continue

    

if list == []:
    quit()

mx = max(list,key=float)
mn = min(list,key=float)

print(f"Maximum = {mx}; Minimum = {mn}")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) but i don't understand the way you put the if-Condition there. Is the "if Check:" something like if Check == True or the check-function is positive?

Comment: The check variable holds the value returned by the check_for_float function. The function returns a value when a valid argument is passed and returns False otherwise. So, in this notation, a non-empty variable corresponds to True while an empty variable corresponds to False.